Quorum private node peer count is not updating, it is 0
Currently, I'm trying to set up a quorum private network using this link. I have followed all the setup and run 5 nodes as well. but when I run geth attach data/geth.ipc inside a node 0 and try to get net.peerCount the output is 0 instead of 4. Can anyone guide me here on what I did wrong? 
Geth version: 1.11.6-stable
Command used for node 0 :
geth --datadir data \
--networkid 1337 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 \
--syncmode full \
--mine --miner.threads 1 --miner.gasprice 0 \
--http --http.addr 127.0.0.1 --http.port 22000 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*" \
--ws --ws.addr 127.0.0.1 --ws.port 32000 --ws.origins "*" \
--http.api admin,eth,debug,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 \
--ws.api admin,eth,debug,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 \
--unlock ${ADDRESS} --allow-insecure-unlock --password ./data/keystore/accountPassword \
--port 30300 --miner.etherbase 0xd4eBe35Ef9857F44f44c6dEB73766B033E903D85

Command used for **node 1 ** :
geth --datadir data \
    --networkid 1337 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 \
    --syncmode full \
    --mine --miner.threads 1 --miner.gasprice 0 \
    --http --http.addr 127.0.0.1 --http.port 22001 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*" \
    --ws --ws.addr 127.0.0.1 --ws.port 32001 --ws.origins "*" \
    --http.api admin,eth,debug,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 \
    --ws.api admin,eth,debug,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 \
    --unlock ${ADDRESS} --allow-insecure-unlock --password ./data/keystore/accountPassword \
    --port 30301 --miner.etherbase 0xd4eBe35Ef9857F44f44c6dEB73766B033E903D85 --authrpc.port 8552

And likewise for nodes 2,3 & 4 only the Ip and port are different.
Also, every node block number is different; they are not in sync mode 1 is on 116 and the second is on 78.

I found a solution, In the node-0 folder, run the following command:
geth attach data/geth.ipc

admin.addPeer("enode://Id-node1@127.0.0.1:port?discport=0&raftport=port");

If you have 5 running nodes, you need to add 4 of them as admin peers inside node-0. After that, you can run:
net.peerCount It will output 4, indicating that all the nodes are in sync mode
